# To have no memory

Tags: single-word-requests

What adjective (or possibly noun) could refer to someone having no memory of what happened some time before?

Example: *"He woke up _______ of the events from last night"*

I found *amnesic*, but I am not sure it would apply.

Comment: "completely unaware", "devoid of memories", "blissfully unaware" (if the memories would have been bad ones)

Comment: Does "unaware" mean a loss of memory? I thought it would only mean you did not know about it in the first place.

Comment: actually it could mean either, but it might be more **commonly** used in the case where you didn't know in the first place (which makes it less suitable as a choice here).

Comment: "unrecollecting" may fit, but the word is not referenced in dictionaries.

Comment: "He woke up with no memory of the events from last night."

Comment: Or *with no recollection*, though that can mean memories that have faded rather than have been formed in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps **ignorant**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use **oblivious**.

He woke up **oblivious** of the events from last night

From Merriam-Webster's dictionary:

> Full Definition of oblivious
>
> 1  lacking remembrance, memory, or mindful attention
>
> 2  lacking active conscious knowledge or awareness —usually used with of or to

(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivious)